# Crashing Pointer Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Code::Blocks, Win7, C++

Hi, I'm creating an overview project for myself, and an integral part includes doing an Exchange Sort in descending order. I've created a simple trial run to test the concept.

Embarrassingly enough, I can't get past creating the array without the project crashing. This only happens when I create the array with pointers (My project's arrays are pointers, which is why I need this to work). The code compiles fine, but when I run it, I get a Window's notification that "ArrayTest.exe has stopped working"

When I print out each dereferenced value, I get:

"The original order: 1 13 5 7 2 "

When I print out each value's address, I get:

"The original order: 0x28ff08 0x28ffc4 0x760c8cd5 0x6aadab61 0xfffffffe "

The last address showed up when using an array length of 6, and crashes as well. Am I blind to a simple error in my code, or is this a hardware issue?

```
//filename ArrayTest
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *j[5];
    (*j)[0] = 1;
    (*j)[1] = 13;
    (*j)[2] = 5;
    (*j)[3] = 7;
    (*j)[4] = 2;

    cout << "The original order: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << (*j)[i] << " ";
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have declared `j` as an array of integer pointers, and not as an array of integers themselves!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're allocating an array of 5 pointers to int, not an array of 5 integers. Try to init the array like this: `int j[5];`

Your code writes your values 1, 13, 5, 7, 2 to the dereferenced pointers in your pointer array. Since they are uninitialized, they contain garbage and thus you're writing to random addresses in memory, which leads to the crash.

Comment: Thanks! Your uninitialized statement helped me see what I was blind to. I needed to make each value in the array a 'new int' before I properly store values in them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `int *j[5];` carefully. This is an array of *pointers*.

Those pointers are not pointing to memory that you own.

So the behaviour on dereferencing them is undefined.

Trivial fix: use `int j[5];` instead, and `j[0] = 1` etc.

When analysing code problems consider these numbers as approximating the probability of the error location:

> 99.0% - your code
>
> 0.9% - the standard library
>
> 0.09% - the compiler
>
> 0.009% - the operating system
>
> 0.001% - the hardware

Comment: Thanks so much! I never considered it because that statement worked perfectly for an array I made with a class type. Did I do that array wrong then, or is the parenthesis only needed for type int?

Comment: Even though the figures in the above table sound valid, I couldn't help but wonder how did you reach to those exact figures (up to 3 decimal digits)! Any source?

Comment: University days I think, but didn't you know that 98% of statistics are made up on the spot ;-) ?

Comment: I'm aware how they are made, but I was wondering if such stuff exists in the remaining 2% :-P

Comment: Where did you get those percentages from?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pointer on array, you have to use this syntax

```
int array[5];
int (*j)[5] = &array;

(*j)[0] = 42;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, firstly, the correct syntax is `int j[5];` but that's C, not C++.

use `std::array` - actual C++ and with compile-time checking.